# CSS to move text to new line on horizontal menu

Tags: html, css

I have a simple horizontal menu. On some of the menu headings, i would like to split them so the text starts on a new line.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="tabs">
<li>
    <div class="home">              
            Home            
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="contact">               
            How to
            Contact Us
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="products">              
            About Our
            Products
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.tabs ul {  
    list-style: none;
}

.tabs li {  
    display: inline-block;
}
```

So, what i am trying to do is, rather than appear as **About Our Products**.. Instead:

**About Our**

**Products**

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oampz/dWbx5/

**Ideally without using br**

Comment: cant you just use <br />

Comment: Ideally without using <br>

Comment: okay, then you will have to look into max-width i'm guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So like I said in the comment, you can maybe use `max-width`

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dWbx5/7/) is a fiddle using it.

**EDIT:** I added it to the inline CSS, but you can move it into your CSS page.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a break `<br />`?

```
<div class="products">              
    About Our<br />Products
</div>
```

I also prefer to use a `float: left;` on the li instead of inline-block, it's easier (and more logic) to work with:

http://jsfiddle.net/2EDbr/

Comment: Thanks, ideally without using <br>

Comment: If you want to use it without `<br />`, place another `<div>` around 'products', or give the li a fixed width, so the text automatically jumps to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div >              

        About Our
    </div>
<div>
     Products
</div>
```

similarly u can use for all

http://jsfiddle.net/dWbx5/4/